# How does \r,\n,\b works in this program

Tags: c, gcc, escaping

Can anyone tell me how i got the **output:hai** for the following code?

```
   int main()
   {
   printf("\nab");
   printf("\bsi");
   printf("\rha");
   return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They work as they should!!

`\n` => Newline, Go to Vertically next position in the same column
`\b` => BackSpace, Go to one position backwards
`\r` => Carriage Return, Same as Home Key in Keyboard

Elaborate Explanation:

`\r`**:**

Move cursor to Home position in the same row.

`\b`**:**

Move cursor one position backwards on same row, if not at Home position.

`\n`**:**

Edit (suggested by interjay) : According to C Standard, should move the cursor to Home position of next line irrespective of platform.

Output after First `printf`:

`ab`

Output after Second `printf`:

`asi`

Output after Third `printf`:

`hai`

Comment: `\n` goes to the first column of the next line.

Comment: @interjay : Now read my answer

Comment: @interjay i think not on windows, that's why you have to say `\r\n`

Comment: __In Windows, Enter means \n\r both together.__ Isn't it `\r\n` ?

Comment: @A4L and 0xF1: You're wrong, if you don't believe me run `printf("abc\ndef\n");` and see what you get.

Comment: @nIcEcOw : I don't remember the order exactly, just that both are there.

Comment: @interjay it gets automatically traslated to `\r\n` in text mode

Comment: @interjay :  In windows, `\n` is translated to `\r\n` inside `printf`.

Comment: @0xF1 : I do remember that, since, I once said the same thingy what you wrote to my teacher, and she rectified me the other day :-) +1 for the explanation though :-)

Comment: @A4L and 0xF1: I know it gets translated. That's why what you said (about `\n` staying in the same column) is wrong, unless you are writing to a binary file (which isn't the case here). You are confusing two different things here (the meaning of control characters in C, and the meaning of control characters in Windows). It's only the meaning in C that's important here.

Comment: I'll even quote the C standard: "\n (new line) Moves the active position to the initial position of the next line."

Comment: @interjay : I got my mistake, `\n` works the same on Unix & Windows although it is not translated to anything in Unix. Therefore `\n` should bring cursor to beginning of next line. I have updated my answer also. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty obvious.

The program start with printing **\nab**. Here, **\n** means, **goto next line**. So, the cursor will go onto next line and display rest of the characters, as:

**ab**

Then, the program prints **\bsi**. Here, **\b** means, **go back by one character** and print rest of the characters. So the out become:

**asi**

Now, Finally, the program prints **\rha**. Here, **\r** means, go back to the starting of the line and print rest of the characters. So, the output becomes:

**hai**

Answer (score 1):

**For me it doesn't!**

On my *mac* with `c11` (-std=c11) the *output* on the console is:

```
(emtpy line)
asi
ha
```